# Finding local mins in an array

Tags: algorithm, f#

Is there a easy way to determine the local min and maxes of an array of values.  For example

```
Element Value   Note
1         1 
2         3 
3         5 
4         6 
5         7       max
5         5 
6         4       min
7         6 
8         9 
9         10      max
10        8 
11        7 
12        5      min
13        10
```

so an array that is defined like:

```
let arr = [|1;3;5;6;7;5;4;6;9;10;8;7;5;10|]
```

would identify

```
mins  = [|4;5|]
```

and

```
maxs  = [|7;10|]
```

It could be a list or Sequence as well as an array.  Two questions

1. Is there any faciliities in F# that that lend themselves to this task
2. Is there a common algorithm for determining either the mins or maxs or both?
3. If writing from scratch should it be approached functionally or imperatively?

Thx

Comment: You want to divide the array into strictly increasing runs?

Comment: How exactly do you define local max and min?

Comment: @SLaks I think, he wants to find all numbers _i_ for which 'a[i-1] > a[i] < a[i+1]' and call it _mins_. What I don't understand is where the problem. Just iterate through the numbers and compare.

Comment: Dumb question I guess--why isn't mins = [|1;3|]?

Comment: plot the points, and connect them by a line and examine "the valleys" and the lowest points in each valley is the min.  I am working with smoothed stock quotes, and investigate market timing by individual stock picker.  These mins represent optimal entry points for long picks

Comment: @akaphenom--ah, thanks for explaining that--figured I must be missing something.

Answer (score 11):

This looks like a job for... [Seq.windowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340420.aspx)!  <cue superhero music>

```
let arr = [|1;3;5;6;7;5;4;6;9;10;8;7;5;10|] 

let _,mins,maxs = 
    arr |> Seq.windowed 3 |> Seq.fold (fun (i,mins,maxs) [|a;b;c|] -> 
    if a>b&&b<c then   (i+1, i::mins,    maxs)
    elif a<b&&b>c then (i+1,    mins, i::maxs)
    else               (i+1,    mins,    maxs)) (1,[],[])

arr |> Seq.iteri (fun i x -> printfn "%2d: %2d" i x)
printfn "mins %A" mins
printfn "maxs %A" maxs
(*
 0:  1
 1:  3
 2:  5
 3:  6
 4:  7
 5:  5
 6:  4
 7:  6
 8:  9
 9: 10
10:  8
11:  7
12:  5
13: 10
mins [12; 6]
maxs [9; 4]
*)
```

Comment: I like the approach, not having to worry about navigating array indexes etc.  the windowed function is an interesting - obviously I didn't think of using it in this problem, however I used it for calcing moving averages earlier today...

Comment: I liked this answer so much I made an inefficient (but more me-readable) version!

Comment: I am following up on old unanswered questions, the problem with this solution is it falls apart on duplicate values...

Comment: I am unclear what you are saying, can you show a testcase that it fails on?  (perhaps if you mean adjacent same values, just turn e.g. `<` to `<=` in the `if`s?)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Brian's answer, I slightly prefer this version:

```
let arr = [|1;3;5;6;7;5;4;6;9;10;8;7;5;10|] 

let find_min_max input = 
    let windows = Seq.windowed 3 input 
    let mins = Seq.filter (fun [|a;b;c|] -> a>b && b<c) windows
               |> Seq.map (fun [|a;b;c|] -> b)
    let maxs = Seq.filter (fun [|a;b;c|] -> a<b && b>c) windows
               |> Seq.map (fun [|a;b;c|] -> b)

    mins, maxs


let mins, maxs = find_min_max arr 

printfn "mins %A" mins
printfn "maxs %A" maxs
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Massif's answer, which is based on Brian's answer, I'd problably roll the filter and map into one:

```
let find_min_max input =  
    let windows = Seq.windowed 3 input  
    let mins = Seq.choose (fun [|a;b;c|] -> if a>b && b<c then Some(b) else None) windows 
    let maxs = Seq.choose (fun [|a;b;c|] -> if a<b && b>c then Some(b) else None) windows 

    mins, maxs
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be trivial to write

```
for x from 0 to size-2:
if (a[x] > a[x+1] && a[x+1] < a[x+2]) // also, there should be bound checking
    //a[x+1] is a min!
    minima.cram(x+1)
if (a[x] < a[x+1] && a[x+1] > a[x+2]) // also, there should be bound checking
    //a[x+1] is a max!
    maxima.cram(x+1)
```

Or have I oversimplified?

Comment: Y  - that simple, however as I am implementing in F# I am attempting to find a more functional approach. As far as imperative approach this is it...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a functional example, you could probably do (in Ruby)

```
def derivative_signs(list)
  (0..list.length-2).map { |i| (list[i+1] - list[i]) <=> 0 }
  ## <=> is the "rocketship" operator which is basically: be -1 if number is negative
  ##                                                      be 0 if number is zero
  ##                                                      be 1 if number is positive
  ## Alternatively, one could use x / x.abs, with an exception if x == 0
end

def derivative(list)
  (0..list.length-2).map { |i| list[i+1] - list[i] }
end
```

Coming from calculus, minimums/maximums are when the first derivative changes signs.  So one could look through `derivative_signs(arr)` and find all of the sign changes.

```
first_derivative_signs = derivative_signs(arr)
# => [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
```

Alternatively, you could also do

```
second_derivative = derivative(derivative_signs(arr))
```

On the list you provided, you'll get:

```
[0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 2]
```

It's clear to see that values with second derivative `-2` are maximums, and values with second derivative `2` are minimums.  The index of the second derivative is the index of the original list + 1.  So the `second_derivative[4]` that is a `-2` corresponds to `arr[5]` (7), which is a maximum.

Why do we do a "normal" derivative the second time, instead of a derivative_sign?

This is because when a value repeats twice in a row, you'll get unwanted behavior.

For example, consider

```
[1, 3, 6, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 9, 10, 8, 7, 5, 10]
# first_derivative_signs =>  [1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
# second_derivative_signs => [0, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1]
# second_derivative       => [0, -1, 1, -2, 0, 2, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 2]
```

Note that `second_derivative_signs` throws us some "false" minimums/maximums, while `second_derivative`, when we check for only `-2` and `2`, is good.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Seq.pairwise` to get each number and its predecessor. Then you can calculate the difference between each number and its predecessor to get the *difference* between all values.

In the third step, you go over the differences and look for sign changes. When ever the sign changes, you know that the value *before* the sign change was an extremum (either min or max).

I don’t know F# at all, but the first step should look like this:

```
let diffs = Seq.pairwise arr |> Seq.map (-)
```