# detecting general pattern of local maxima in 1D Java array

Tags: java, android, arrays, graph-algorithm

I am trying to make a simple pitch detection application for an Android phone.  I have gotten the phone to display a graph of the autocorrelation values I have computed, which are stored in a one dimensional array of doubles.  Now I need to figure out how to detect repeating patterns within the array.  Here is a screenshot of the autocorrelation graph with me humming a steady pitch:

[image: screenshot of my autocorrelation graph when humming a steady pitch]

I tried implementing the recursive peak-finding algorithm for 1D arrays given in this slide deck: http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec02.pdf but I got out of memory errors on the Android.

Next I tried implementing something like this algorithm for finding the second derivative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869172 but the autocorrelation values coming from the phone are so jittery that it finds too many minima and maxima.

What I need to figure out how to do is to apply some kind of filter to the autocorrelation data to smooth it out but I suck at math and have no idea what to do.  I tried rounding the autocorrelation values to only a few decimal places but I didn't get the results I was looking for.

Basically I need help in figuring out how I can find the overall maxima (actually just the first one would probably be ok) of a repeating pattern.  In the screenshot above, the pattern is a tall peak followed by two shorter peaks.  I need to know when the second tall peak happens so that I can calculate the pitch.

Comment: Mean or medain filters can smooth your signal. define a window length that fits your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is what I ended up doing.  (Sorry it took me so long to come back to this question to post the answer.)

```
double frequency = findFrequency(lowPassFilter(signal));

private double findFrequency(double[] signal) {
    int[] signs = new int[signal.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < signal.length - 1; i++) {
        double diff = signal[i+1] - signal[i];
        if (diff < 0) {
            signs[i] = -1;
        } else if (diff == 0) {
            signs[i] = 0;
        } else {
            signs[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    int[] secondDerivatives = new int[signs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < signs.length - 1; i++) {
        secondDerivatives[i] = signs[i+1] - signs[i];
    }
    double biggestSoFar = 0.0;
    int indexOfBiggestSoFar = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < secondDerivatives.length; i++) {
        if (secondDerivatives[i] == -2 && signal[i] > biggestSoFar) {
            biggestSoFar = signal[i];
            indexOfBiggestSoFar = i;
        }
    }
    return 1 / (double)indexOfBiggestSoFar * AudioListener.SAMPLE_RATE;
}

private double[] lowPassFilter(double[] signal) {
    double alpha = 0.15;
    for (int i = 1; i < signal.length; i++ ) {
        signal[i] = signal[i] + alpha * (signal[i] - signal[i-1]);
    }
    return signal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to estimate the frequency of the peaks of amplitude in the sample data. You can do this without having to manually find estimate the peaks and then work out frequency. Instead you can use a Fast Fourier Transform, this transforms from a graph of amplitude against time into a graph of frequency against time.  There is a good description of the concept in general here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

...and there are several Java libraries that implement the transform including 
Apache Commons Math - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/transform/FastFourierTransformer.html 
and
JTransform - https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms